# Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. phusion passenger nginx

Tags: nginx, passenger

Its my first time setting up passenger and nginx

I am mostly going through this guide

https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04

```
deploy@localhost:/var/log/nginx$ tail error.log 
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'


[ 2015-01-15 21:29:59.5563 22279/7f4ceffff700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is f4e9d607. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

I have added the following to my generated nginx.conf file

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

I am using rbenv

my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;
        passenger_enabled on;
        #passenger_load_shell_envvars off
        rails_env production;
        root /home/deploy/appname/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
           root html;
           passenger_enabled on;
        }
}
```

I tried moving the rbenv paths before the completion/exit in my bashrc. I have also tried to not load bashrc.

my deploy.rb looks fine

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano

lock '3.3.5'

set :application, 'appname'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:myself/appname.git'

#Basic Settings
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/appname"
set :user, 'deploy'
#set :use_sudo, false
set :port, 22
set :rails_env, :production
#set :use_sudo, true

#symbolic files and directories
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets log bin vendor/bundle public/system}

set :log_level, :info

#setting rbenv settings
# set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.2'
# set :rbenv_type, :user
# set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
# set :rbenv_path, '/home/deploy/.rbenv'
# set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}
# set :rbenv_roles, :all 

#just pointing to our unicorn.rb
#set :unicorn_config_path, "config/unicorn.rb"

#capistrano tasks and processes

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, "deploy:cleanup"

end
```

I am using cap 3. I commented out the rbenv because i figured passenger can find it with the passenger ruby insertion.